# google voice number and google hangouts and being overseas

Tags: google-hangouts, google-voice

when I lived in the US, I had a AT&T cell plus a google voice number.
Now I moved to Istanbul & stopped the AT&T line.

My android & my iPhone ( which I had activated while in the US ) still continue to work in Istanbul with that old google voice. Which means, I can place calls to US and receive calls from US ( just like I was in the States ) using that old google voice number.

Now my question is the following:

I'm going to be getting the new note 7 by purchasing it here in Istanbul. Will I be able to use the hangouts apps & my existing google voice number on the new phone?

OR WILL IT TELL ME SOMETHING LIKE, I need an active US number, and that they will send me a verification code to that US number? If so, I'm out of luck.

The bottom line is I'd like to get a new phone in Istanbul and continue to use the google voice & hangout apps as I'm doing now. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merhaba! I live in Istanbul as well, and use my pre-existing Hangouts/Voice number just fine, on a phone I bought here in Turkey. I just logged into my Google account on my new phone, and everything worked. You should be just fine!

Your Voice account is tied only to your Google account, not any US number. I've completely deleted any US number from my account, and there was no issue whatsoever.

You won't be able to automatically forward Google Voice calls to your Turkish number, but you will receive & make calls & texts via the app (over your 3g/wifi connection).

saygılar
~peter

Comment: Peter, "Saygilar bizden". :) -- Thank you for your comforting answer, Nothing beats receiving a feedback from someone who has been in the same shoes as I was worried about. So, on the new phone, you downloaded the google voice app and at the time of set up, you chose "route all international calls ( incoming or outcoming ) thru your google voice number right?

Comment: So just to make sure I've got this. I have Google voice, G Hangouts, and a T-Mobile number. I have my text messages synchronized with my G Hangouts as well. I leave the country in 2 weeks for 8-12 months. All I have to do is unsynch my sms, delete G Voice from my cell, and insert my new SIM. Then I can manage my voice and text from my PC. Do I have this?